# How to make buttons blink in sequence programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Without using Cocos2D or other frameworks, I'd like to make some UIButtons blink in sequence, each one spaced 1 second apart. However only the first one blinks! Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
-(void)pressTimerButton{

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self selector:@selector(timerFires)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[timer fire];
}

- (void) timerFires{

ComputerStringsArray_A=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[ComputerStringsArray_A addObject:@"1"];
[ComputerStringsArray_A addObject:@"2"];
[ComputerStringsArray_A addObject:@"3"];
[ComputerStringsArray_A addObject:@"4"];
[ComputerStringsArray_A addObject:@"5"];

NoElementsInMutableArray = [ComputerStringsArray_A count];

NSString *ReadString = ComputerStringsArray_A[increment];

if      ([ReadString isEqualToString:one])   {Button = Button_01;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:two])   {Button = Button_02;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:three]) {Button = Button_03;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:four])  {Button = Button_04;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:five])  {Button = Button_05;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:six])   {Button = Button_06;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:seven]) {Button = Button_07;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:eight]) {Button = Button_08;}
else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:nine])  {Button = Button_09;}

[self FlashButton];

increment++;

//Don't try to flash a button beyond the length of the array
if (increment > NoElementsInMutableArray-1)
{
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
}
}

-(void) FlashButton
//- (void)FlashButton:(id)anElement
{
self.Button.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.18
                      delay:0.7
                    options:
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |
 //UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
 UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |
 UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction

                 animations:^{
                     self.Button.alpha = 0.02f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     //At the end of the flashing return opacity to 100% and color to white
                     self.Button.alpha = 1.0f;
                     Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                 }];
}
```

Comment: Do u want serial blink like something is moving linearly?

Comment: I want them to blink one after the other one: 1..2..3..4..5..etc. When the following button blinks, the previous one has already stopped blinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help solve your problem?

```
- (void) animateButtonSequence {

    NSString *ReadString = ComputerStringsArray_A[increment];

    UIButton * buttonToFlash;

    if      ([ReadString isEqualToString:one])   {buttonToFlash = Button_01;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:two])   {buttonToFlash = Button_02;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:three]) {buttonToFlash = Button_03;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:four])  {buttonToFlash = Button_04;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:five])  {buttonToFlash = Button_05;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:six])   {buttonToFlash = Button_06;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:seven]) {buttonToFlash = Button_07;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:eight]) {buttonToFlash = Button_08;}
    else if ([ReadString isEqualToString:nine])  {buttonToFlash = Button_09;}

    // Perhaps easier to just have an array of your buttons?
    // All the above code would just be

    UIButton * buttonToFlash = btnsArray[increment];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{

                         // button flash animation

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             increment = increment + 1;
                             if (increment == ComputerStringsArray_A.count) {
                                 increment = 0;

                                 // done animating, proceed here

                             }
                             else {
                                 [self performSelector:@selector(animateButtonSequence) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
                             }
                         }
                     }];
}
```

This way you wouldn't have to keep track of your timers.

Comment: It sounds like it may be the way to go.. When and how do you define currentAnimationBlockIndex please? Cheers

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be 'increment', I noticed you using that variable in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having all the buttons in an array rather than trying to perform string comparisons to make the decision. For example:

```
buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:button_01,button_02,button_03,button_04,button_05,button_06,button_07,button_08,button_09, nil];
```

And then have an integer counter (declared as an instance variable of the class) initiated when you start the timer. The your timerFires code becomes much simpler.

```
- (void) timerFires{
    Button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:counter];
    [self flashButton];
    counter++;
    if(counter == buttonArray.count){
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

In the process, you don't lose references to your buttons, and it does not take any additional memory.

EDIT: Ok so here's my implementation of a similar function in one of my projects. The code definitely works - I just checked it.

```
- (void) animateKeyboardButton{
    if(counter>0)
        ((UIButton*)[keyboard objectAtIndex:counter - 1]).alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    if(counter <keyboard.count)
        ((UIButton*) [keyboard objectAtIndex:counter]).alpha = 0.2f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    counter ++;
    if(counter == keyboard.count+1){
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
- (void) animateKeyboardWithInterval: (float) interval{
    counter = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(animateKeyboardButton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}
```

This is code from one of my projects, which has a 28-key keyboard, stored in a NSMutableArray object. The Animation works perfectly here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but it does not solve the problem. Still, only the first button of the sequence blinks. I want to blink them in sequence: 1..2..3..4..5..etc

Comment: Perhaps replace [self flashButton]; with [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(flashButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; - maybe it's trying to change UI elements from a non-main thread

Comment: Ok, in that case, did you check if you are adding all the buttons to the array, and that they are not released yet? Confirm the count of the array in the timerFires block by NSLog. Check if the function is getting called repeatedly. Try creating a breakpoint and seeing how the control flows from statement to statement. I don't see any problem per se with the code here.

Comment: Yes, the timer gets called repeatedly increasing the count. That's why I am puzzled. And the array is complete.

Comment: I will now post the code for the flashing button in case it helps

Comment: Puzzling indeed. The only logical path is that there is something wrong with the code you're using for the animation bit. Perhaps you can post it up as an edit to your question so we can look at that too? Also, did you check if the objects in the array are the ones that are supposed to be there: NSLog("objectAtIndex %d = %@", counter, [buttonArray objectAtIndex: counter]);

Comment: Might be a very stupid point, but how about changing Button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex: counter]; to self.Button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex: counter]; Also, try to use a smaller delay, maybe 0.3 and see if that works.

Comment: Ok so this question began to bug me, so I decided to try it in one of my projects, and I've edited the code. Let me know if it works, because that code block works for me.